# How to compare one item with two items at a time from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if this has been asked before, I have been looking for an answer for hours without success.

So, I have a number (it's actually a class object, but for example's sake it may be better to explain using integers): 1, and a list of unique numbers (my number not included).

Example: [2, 5, 3, 8, 9, 4...]

What I want to do is compare my number (1) with all numbers from the list, but two items/pair at a time, so the first ones here would be (2, 5). Then, with these three numbers (1, 2, 5) I can check if they meet a condition from a function of mine. If not, take my number again (1) and compare it with the next two items (3, 8) from the list and so on until the condition for all three numbers is met (or not).

Can you guys please help me out on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two adjacent items or two any distinct items?

Comment: You'll probably find the zip clustering idiom useful here.  Try `for a, b in zip(*[iter(your_list)]*2): print(a, b)`.  Decide what you want to happen if the input list has an odd length

Comment: Doesn't matter the order between the list items. Just want all items in list to be checked with my number at some point, one pair at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just grab the elements separately and use it as arguments for you compare function, like that:

```
a = 1
b = [2,3,4,5,6,7]

for i in range(0, len(b), 2):
    print(a, b[i], b[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(lst)-2, 2):
    tmp = lst[i:i+2].append(1)
    check(tmp)
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Gives me two None values if I print the result. Why'd that be?